# Very Slow performance with sqlsrv PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have been using `mssql_` functions on my app, but finally have succumbed to requests from members of SO to change to PDO functions.

However the microsoft PDO driver is very slow, a request to return 20 rows from a table with 10,000 records takes between 5 and 10 seconds, with `mssql_` functions it took milliseconds.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution, but I turned off connectionpooling in the connection string and it seems to have solved my performance issues.

```
server=mymachine.example.com;database=mydb;connectionpooling=0
```

Comment: this did nothing for the performance in my app + server setup. I switched to pdo(odbc) and accessed SQL server via the native client to speed up performance on my app (though this setup has its own problems). on linux we now use pdo(odbc) via freetds as well.